# Move text around on xml using sed

Tags: xml, linux, sed, move

EDIT: Thanks for the help anyway, forget it.. i'll parse the xml directly on my server with java, and then download it to my device directly from the server... it's easier and faster that way...

Can someone help me with sed command? i'm not so good with that :)

I removed the `<title lang="en">` line and let only the "pt" line.. (device limitation)
this i already did and it's working fine, like this:

```
sed -i '/<title lang=\"en\">/d' xmltv_clarotv.xml
```

now, i'm trying to do the code that i said and plus get the content from `<date></date>` and put it inside the `<title lang="pt">` that should result in something like this:
`<title lang="pt">[2011] Gigantes de Aço</title>`  note that not every `<programme>` have the field `<date>`
can someone give me an help with that? it need be with `sed` command and the device that i'll execute it does not have much RAM and native functions...

i'm trying do that because the device that will parse it only recognize the 'title' and 'desc' field...

A little piece of the xml:

```
<programme start="20120923200000 -0300" stop="20120923222500 -0300" channel="T4H" program_id="0000278093" event_id="000000000887005" series_key="">
<title lang="pt">Gigantes de Aço</title>
<title lang="en">Real Steel</title>
<desc>Viva a adrenalina e o frenesi de uma atividade como a luta de Robôs. Esta é a história de um ex-campeão de boxe que, empurrado pelo forte desejo de uma criança, volta ao mundo da luta como um misterioso andróide. - www.revistaeletronica.com.br </desc>
<credits>
<director>Shawn Levy</director>
<actor>Hugh Jackman</actor>
<actor>Dakota Goyo</actor>
<actor>Evangeline Lilly</actor>
<actor>Anthony Mackie</actor>
<actor>Kevin Durand</actor>
<actor>Hope Davis</actor>
</credits>
<date>2011</date>
<category lang="pt">Filme</category>
<category lang="pt">Ação</category>
<country>EUA/Índia</country>
<video>
<colour>yes</colour>
</video>
<rating system="Advisory">
<value>Programa impróprio para menores de 14 anos</value>
</rating>
<star-rating>
<value>4/5</value>
</star-rating>
</programme>
```

Comment: Don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job. Regex is not the right tool for processing Xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use `XSLT` to recreate the `XML` way you want. ([`Ecplise`](http://www.eclipse.org/) has a great XSLT engine to achieve this).

Tutorials

- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/xslt/a/xslt-tutorial-1.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp
- http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21846
- http://oreilly.com/catalog/orxmlapp/chapter/ch07.pdf

> Use the right tool for the job. Regex is not the right tool for processing Xml. ([Pawelless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel), 2012)

Comment: the problem is that i'll not run it on pc, it should be executed on Digital Satellite TV Decoder and it does not have much resource available... =\

Comment: Have you had a look for XSLT engines based on your digitial satellite TV model? (I'm sure there are some available), I was referring to Eclipse for when you want to build your schema.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<programme/,/^<\/programme>/!b;/^<programme/{h;d};/^<title lang="en"/d;H;/^<\/programme>/!d;x;s/\(<title[^>]*>\)\(.*<date>\(.*\)<\/date>\)/\1[\3] \2/' file
```

Essentially, you want to store the lines between `programme` tags, delete the English title and amend the remaining title (or not) with the date.

Explanation:

- `/^<programme/,/^<\/programme>/!b` only process `progrmame` lines
- `/^<programme/{h;d}` first line, overwrite anything in the hold space (HS) and delete
- `/^<title lang="en"/d` delete the English title
- `H` append all other lines to the HS
- `/^<\/programme>/!d` delete all line except the last
- `x` swap pattern space (PS) with HS
- `s/\(<title[^>]*>\)\(.*<date>\(.*\)<\/date>\)/\1[\3] \2/` amend the title

Comment: did not work here ... it just removed the title "en" and doubled the "program", the "pt" title still the same...

Comment: I made a mistake, leaving in the `p` command which was no longer needed. The command has been removed and tested against the example you supplied. I am using GNU sed, perhaps this causes you a problem?